# Confused with Java Objects

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner with Java, and I am trying the following code:

```
public class MovieTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movie one = new Movie();
        one.title = "Gone with the Stock";
        one.playIt();
        System.out.println(one.title);   // Works!! one.title is equal to Dora

        Movie [] arr = new Movie[2];
        arr[0].playIt();
        System.out.println(arr[0].title); //Error: Null Pointer Exception

    }
}


class Movie {

        String title;

        void playIt() {
             title = "Dora";
        }

 }
```

Why does the code works in the assignment of a primitive variable while it doesn't when using an array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because all you have in `arr` is an array of object references, but they're not initialized to point at any actual objects.

You also need to do:

```
arr[0] = new Movie();
arr[1] = new Movie();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is in your movie array yet.  You need to put objects in your array before you can act upon them.

Between "Movie [] arr = new Movie[2];" and "arr[0].playIt();", you need to assign Movie objects to your array in order to perform the .playIt() function and have anything actually occur.

Answer (score 1):

The `NPE` is in the previous line, at `arr[0].playIt();`

It's got nothing to do with your object though, it's the fact that your array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
Movie [] arr = new Movie[2]; // creates an empty array of two elements [null, null]

// now lets add Movie objects
arr[0] = new Movie();
...
```

I would suggest to use ArrayList instead of array:

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
movies.add(new Movie());
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill your array. All you did so far was allocate space for an array of movie objects. You didn't put any objects into that space. you can use 
arr[i]=new Movie(); where i is the array index